# Unable to use API key with GCP's python discovery client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, client, google-api-python-client

my question is can we bind roles to API Keys if so, how?

Are the API Keys supported for all the services across GCP if not which ones?

also, why to use service account over API keys?

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

storage_service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', developerKey="AIzaSyhidingKeyVm60c")

storage_service.buckets().list(project='my-project').execute()
```

Comment: There are two major APIs (Google and Google Cloud). Google Cloud Storage does not support API Keys. API Keys are supported by some Google services (not Google Cloud services). See @DazWilkin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read Google's documentation, e.g. [authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication), it is definitive and comprehensive.

API keys:

- authenticate apps (not users).
- are supported across Google's (not only Google Cloud Platform) services.
- should be used judiciously if at all.
- aren't used with roles.

Roles are an element of role-based access control (RBAC) and, with Google Cloud IAM ([overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)) are bound to users, service accounts and groups to define access policies.

Programs accessing data not owned by users should generally run as a service account.

Programs accessing data owned by users should authenticate using the user's credentials.